# How to get Hibernate to scan for Entities in a jar file included in the jar

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, persistence.xml

I have a vexing problem.
I'm upgrading stuff to j11 and the latest of everything but I can't change too much of the app itself. The created jar file contains within itself a jar file that contains mapped entities, like this:

jar

- BOOT-INF

  - classes

    - application classes
  - lib

    - entity lib
- META-INF

  - persistence.xml

In my `persistence.xml` I refer to the entity lib through the <jar-file> directive like so:

> ```
>             <jar-file>BOOT-INF/lib/EntityLib-1.0.jar</jar-file>
> ```

But the scanner can't find it. (I get `java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: BOOT-INF/lib/EntityLib-1.0.jar`)

I've read parts of JSR-338, JPA 2.1 and looked at the examples but I haven't gotten any further.
I'm using Hibernate 5.3.3.Final
This is a spring boot application but the original developers used basic JPA instead of the spring func and I'm not allowed to rewrite the app that much (nor do I want to, to be honest).

EDIT: the app is created through the normal `spring-boot-maven-plugin`.

Comment: Was this JAR generated using the standard procedure (i.e. the default Spring Boot Maven/Gradle plugin config)? I would have expected `persistence.xml` to end up under `BOOT-INF/classes/META-INF`. `lib/EntityLib-1.0.jar` would then be correct

Comment: @crizzis Yes, it uses the spring-boot-maven-plugin

Comment: @crizzis actually, the BOOT-INF/classes/META-INF lib does not exist

Comment: My previous comment might have been unnecessarily confusing. What I meant was I thought `persistence.xml` would normally end up under `BOOT-INF/classes/META-INF` and **not** the root `META-INF`. The persistence provider should then accept a simple `lib/xxx.jar` path. I might be mistaken, though

Comment: @crizzis When running from the command line , BOOT-INF/lib/EntityLib-1.0.jar but in Intellij it fails.